# ASP.NET Web API app that does not rely on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-core

I need to make single-page web application with ASP.NET Web API that does not rely on IIS. From what I've read, I should configure the application to run in an OWIN pipeline and remove any reference to `System.Web`.

Is that correct? Is having a dependence on ISS equivalent to having a reference to `System.Web`?

And the opposite: Is having a reference to `System.Web` equivalent to having a dependence on IIS?

Comment: You can [self host](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) Web API. Then have a separate SPA website communicate with your API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you want to get rid of is **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**.
It is used to enable your **Owin** server to run your **Web Api** on **IIS**.

You can self-host your Web Api (no dependencies on IIS) using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/) package:
  **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost**.

**Summarizing** your web api must rely on these packages only:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
- Microsoft.Owin
- Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
- Newtonsoft.Json

If you want to do some diagnostics you can add:

- Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics

I've published an [experiment](https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiSelfHost) on github for some tests, if you're interested.